# ASP.NET Core Identity UserRole for multi tenant application

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-8

I have  gone through similar questions on stack overflow but there is no proper answer for this.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 8 and EF Core 8 with ASP.NET Core identity.

I have a multi tenant app which uses ASP.NET Core identity with EF Core identity. The problem is with the adding user to a role.

An `Agent` as tenant here, so `AgentId` is `TenantId`.

When a tenant initially signs up, a role for that tenant is created as `Admin`. Then, when another tenant signs up, it creates another role with same name of `Admin`. There is no issue with that, I configured it correctly.

The problem occurs when I try to assign the user from the second tenant to the admin role using

```cs
_userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, roleName);
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element.

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, String normalizedRoleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, String role)
at IBS.Agent.Persistence.Repositories.Security.UserSecurityRepository.CreatePrimaryAdminUser(Guid agentId, String userName, String password, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String timeZone, UserRoleDto role, IdentityRoleClaim`1 roleClaim, Guid countryId) in C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\My Projects\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent.Persistence\Repositories\Security\UserSecurityRespository.cs:line 102
at IBS.Agent.Core.Security.Services.SecurityService.CreatePrimaryAdminUser(PrimaryAdminUserCreateDto model, UserRoleDto role, IdentityRoleClaim`1 roleClaim) in C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\My Projects\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent.Core\Security\Services\SecurityService.cs:line 97
at IBS.Agent.Core.Agents.Services.AgentRegistrationService.RegisterNewAgent(AgentSignupDto model) in C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\My Projects\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent.Core\Agents\Services\AgentRegistrationService.cs:line 34
at IBS.Agent.Api.Controllers.V1.Agents.AgentRegistrationsController.AgentSignup(AgentSignupDto model) in C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\My Projects\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent\IBS.Agent.Api\Controllers\V1\Agents\AgentRegistrationsController.cs:line 16
at lambda_method106(Closure, Object)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|7_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

I understand that the `AddToRoleAsync()` is trying to find the role name using `SingleOrDefault()` without the tenant id. once it found the role name `Admin` twice, it throws this error.

Is there a filter I can apply before that query executes to find the correct role? So that I can filter by tenant id

Comment: "when a tenant initially signsup, a role for that tenant is created as Admin. Then, when another tenant signsup it creates another role with same name Admin. there is no issue with that , i configured it correctly." Why is it creating roles? Roles should be predefined and unique within the system.

Comment: we have the option to create dynamic role and assign predefined claims to a role

Comment: You could provide your own `IUserRoleStore` implementation? But you should probably store your builtin roles separate from the dynamic roles.

Comment: i did not manually implement the `IUserRoleStore`

Comment: If you want to add `.Where` to each query, you would need to. Otherwise you could name all your dynamic roles `$"{tenant}-{name}"`.

Comment: hmm, now that a good idea, never thought of it. thank a alot